# Dynamic Rows with Drop downs

Tags: visualforce

I'm kinda stuck on figuring this out. I'm looking to add dynamic rows containing two drop downs anyone know how i go about doing this?

Comment: Are you asking how to add dynamic rows into a pageblocktable, or how to add custom dropdowns into a row, or both?

Comment: dynamic rows into a pageblocktable

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of adding a new row to your `<apex:pageBlockTable>` dynamically

**Controller**

```
public class YourController {
    public List< ... > rows { get; set; }

    public void addRow() {
        rows.add( ... );
    }
}
```

**Visualforce**

```
....
<apex:commandButton value="Add Row" action="{!addRow}" rerender="dynamicTableContainer"/>
...
<apex:outputPanel id="dynamicTableContainer">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!rows}" var="row">
        ...
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:outputPanel>
```